# Store pig result in a text file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

Hi stackoverflow community;

i'm totally new to pig, i want to STORE the result in a text file and name it as i want. is it possible do this using STORE function.

My code:

```
a = LOAD 'example.csv' USING PigStorage(';');

b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$6,$7,$8,$9,$11,$12,$13,$14,$20,$24,$25;

STORE b INTO ‘myoutput’;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Technically, this will create a directory named 'myoutput' in which there will be one or more part-... files.

Comment: LiMuBei is correct. If your goal is to use csv's that can fit into memory, manipulate them, and store the results as one csv then use R/Python. Tools like Hadoop are intended for large datasets stored in parts. TLDR: don't use a steamroller if all you need is an iron

Answer (score 10):

Yes you will be able to store your result in myoutput.txt and you can load the data into file with any delimiter you want using PigStorage.

```
a = LOAD 'example.csv' USING PigStorage(';');
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$6,$7,$8,$9,$11,$12,$13,$14,$20,$24,$25;
STORE b INTO ‘myoutput.txt’ using PigStorage(';');
```

Comment: Just a note to anyone doing this, you should be able to run grunt> pwd, to see where the output is stored on your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. b will store every row into 25 different columns - $0 to S25.